# How can I make an if, when the lines are finished reading, check if the if is still positive?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I 'am making a recognition program and I have a problem that, i have to recheck if the if is still positive

My code:

```
    {
        RECOGNITION = true;
        engine_load();
    }

    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    PromptBuilder promptBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine NSK = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    
  
    #endregion


    private void speechRecognition_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("speech recognized:" + e.Result.Text.ToString());
    }

    

   
// In this If I have the problem

    private void engine_load()
    {



        if (RECOGNITION == true)
        {
            engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            Grammar g = new DictationGrammar();
            engine.LoadGrammar(g);
            engine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            engine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(engine_SpeechRecognized);
            Console.ReadLine();
            
           
        }

    }
```

What I need is that every time I speak, the system before recognizing the words verify that the variable "Recognition" is true.

If anyone knows how to help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Hi Hiper11, Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be nice if you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help us to understand what problem you are facing

Comment: `if (!RECOGNITION) { return; }`

Comment: When I use the "return" the machine does not detect my voice

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using a while-loop?

```
while(RECOGNITION)
{
    ...
}
```

If you dont want to use while you can add a jump after the if

```
returnHere:

//Your stuff here
if (RECOGNITION == true)
{
    ...
}

//jump back if condition is still true
if(still true) { goto returnHere; }
```

Comment: Advising the use of goto is very **BAD** practice.

Comment: @rioV8 To list all possibilities is never bad. What he wants to use is up to him

Comment: We have passed the BASIC era. Using constructs that are not maintainable is BAD. There are uses for goto but they are very specific and usually there is a much better alternative in C#.

Comment: what I have to do is the same function as while but when I use the while the program crashes , also the goto doesn't work for me since it prevents all the recognition from running any other solution?